# How to download large azure blobls with linux python

Tags: python, linux, azure

I'm fairly new to azure but have managed to cobble together a test script to create containers, list them and even upload/download objects.

Now I want to try and download a large object which I know needs to be done in pieces.  After much digging, the documentation seems weak for linux/python, I managed to find the optional x_ms_range argument to the get_object() call.  After even more digging I found a description of 'range' as 'xx-yy', but when I try to use it to download a portion of an object.  Here's what my code fragment looks like:

```
print "GET 10k"
blob1 = blob_service.get_blob('mycontainer', '10k')
print "LEN blob1:", len(blob1)
blob2 = blob_service.get_blob('mycontainer', '10k', x_ms_range='1-100')
print "LEN blob2:", len(blob2)
```

and as you can see when I run the script it reports this:

```
GET 10k
LEN blob1: 10000
LEN blob2: 10000
```

can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line of code from:

```
blob2 = blob_service.get_blob('mycontainer', '10k', x_ms_range='1-100')
```

to

```
blob2 = blob_service.get_blob('mycontainer', '10k', x_ms_range='bytes=1-100')
```

Based on the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691967.aspx, you would need to prepend `bytes=` when specifying the range.